# Swift: Unable to play each sound sequence based on array

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I am been trying to figure out how to play a sequence of sounds based on values in an array using switch case statement. So far it only plays the last integer corresponding sound.

What I am looking to achieve is when I click Play button, it loops through the soundSeq array values each and play corresponding sound before it stops. But in this case, it only plays the sound for tagid 5.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class UIController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!

    let soundSeq = [2,4,5]

    func playSoundSeq() {
        for tag in soundSeq {
            switch tag {
            case 1 : loopSoundSeq(tagid: tag)
            case 2 : loopSoundSeq(tagid: tag)
            case 3 : loopSoundSeq(tagid: tag)
            case 4 : loopSoundSeq(tagid: tag)
            case 5 : loopSoundSeq(tagid: tag)
            case 6 : loopSoundSeq(tagid: tag)
            case 7 : loopSoundSeq(tagid: tag)
            default : print("no sound played")
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func playButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        playSoundSeq()
    }

    func loopSoundSeq(tagid: Int) {
        var soundURl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "minisound\(tagid)", withExtension: "wav")

        //machinePlay.append(sender.tag)

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURl!)
        }
        catch {
            print(soundURl)
        }

        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for each sound to finish playing before starting the next.  Have your class adopt `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` and implement the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` method `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_:successfully:)` and trigger the next sound in the sequence:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class UIController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

    let soundSeq = [2, 4, 5]
    var index = 0

    func playSoundSeq() {
        if index < soundSeq.count {
            loopSoundSeq(tagid: soundSeq[index])
            index += 1
        }
    }

    @IBAction func playButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        index = 0
        playSoundSeq()
    }

    func loopSoundSeq(tagid: Int) {
        let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "minisound\(tagid)", withExtension: "wav")!

        //machinePlay.append(sender.tag)

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
            audioPlayer.delegate = self
        }
        catch {
            print(soundURL)
        }

        audioPlayer.play()
    }

    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        if flag {
            playSoundSeq()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested this code before posting it, and it plays each sound in sequence.  Are you sure you followed the code exactly?

Comment: Put a `print("in audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying")` line in your `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` function to make sure it is getting hit.

Comment: Mama mia, sorry @vacawama, my fault, I did not remove the case code func bit hence reason for the issue. All working now. You the best. Just one question, how do one make it play fast?

Comment: To make it play twice as fast: add `audioPlayer.enableRate = true`
        `audioPlayer.rate = 2.0` before `audioPlayer.play()`.  You can adjust the `rate` between `0.5` (half-speed) to `2.0` (twice as fast).